# Do Something when user enables new keyboard

Tags: android

I have created a custom keyboard where users will get to enable new input method. But, I want to detect whether they have enabled it or not. I have used following code:

```
 Intent enableIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
 enableIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 getActivity().startActivity(enableIntent);
```

But, I want to change the UI of the program if the user enables my custom created keyboard and do nothing if they don't change. I know I can get the enabled UI list from here:

```
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  String list = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList().toString();
```

This doesnt work like expected. Here is my function

```
 private Boolean checkIfKeyboardIsSelected() {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
        enableIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getActivity().startActivity(enableIntent);




        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        String list = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList().toString();

        Log.e("List", list);

        if(list.contains(KEYBOARDID))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

What should I do?

Comment: I tested your codes, its correct. so what 'This doesnt work like expected' means?

Comment: I meant when I enabled my custom keyboard from the Manage Keyboard section, I want to navigate to different screen, or show some text.

Comment: plz see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
//call this line in some place
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS),1);
```

And override `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    String list = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList().toString();

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (list.contains(KEYBOARDID)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //do what you want
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "bad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way you can kiss someone in SO? Why didn't I even think about startActivityForResult method? YOUR CODE WORKS MATE!